# What can be used to return Neo4J data from a promise in a dialog context or waterfallStepContext step within the Microsoft Bot Framework Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, neo4j, promise, botframework

In this waterfall step,

```js
public async processRequest(stepContext: WaterfallStepContext): Promise<DialogTurnResult> { ...
```

I am trying to return or end the dialog with the following,

`return await stepContext.endDialog(JSON.stringify(dataPayload));`

However I can't return the step inside of the session.run(query) result.

Is there a way to use the Waterfall step to have a response function to return the stepContext?

Here is the sample Neo4j driver session,

```js
session
  .run(query)
  .subscribe({
   onNext: function (record) {
   console.log(record);
   // return await stepContext.endDialog(JSON.stringify('dataPayload')); <-- not intiating
  },
  onCompleted: function () {
  session.close();
  },
  onError: function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly it appears that you would like to wait for the query to complete, buffering all results before proceeding in the waterfall step?

In that case use the promise api:

```
const result = await session.run(query);
session.close(); 
await stepContext.endDialog(JSON.stringify(dataPayload));
```

Comment: yes I need to fix the question. I figured out that you can't return a promise in a forEach loop.

Comment: Yes. Is something is `AsyncIterable` you can use `for await (item of iterable)` - there's an example of that on https://drivine.org (my TypeScript neo driver). Otherwise you can map each item then use Promise.all(...) . . hope it is going well now.